# Array.length as key for a function (solidity)

Tags: key, solidity

My apologies for the newbie question however I am attempting to learn coding and have no other means of finding the solution. I am looking for a way to have a unique key added to the outcome of a function so I can have other iterations of that same function to refer to it if needed.

Please find the code below. When I run the code as it stands it keep asking for a value to be input by the user while I am looking for the code to not ask the user but to use the value that is produced from the gettid() function.

As I am clearly very new to coding so I am also open to suggestions as to improve on the key identifier (it needs to be unique and although my approach is simple it should produce unique values).

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract example{

```
struct Input{
    uint256 gettid;
    string title1;
    string title2;
    string title3;
    string title4;
    string title5;
}
Input[] public inputsArray;

function gettid() public view returns(uint256) {
return inputsArray.length;
}

function addinput(
    uint256 _gettid,
    string memory _title1,
    string memory _title2,
    string memory _title3,
    string memory _title4,
    string memory _title5
    
) public {
    inputsArray.push(Thread(_gettid, _title1, _title2, _title3, _title4, _title5));
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the gettid() function and store the return value in a temporary uint and then push the temp uint to the array. Something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract example{

struct Input{
    uint256 gettid;
    string title1;
    string title2;
    string title3;
    string title4;
    string title5;
}
Input[] public inputsArray;

function gettid() public view returns(uint256) {
return inputsArray.length;
}

function addinput(
    string memory _title1,
    string memory _title2,
    string memory _title3,
    string memory _title4,
    string memory _title5
    
) public {
    uint256 _nextId = gettid();
    inputsArray.push(Thread(_nextId, _title1, _title2, _title3, _title4, _title5));
}}
```